# Write data to multiple BLE(bluetooth) devices

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, nsoperation

Please check the following scenario:

ConnectDevices Class:

This method is for connect to BLE device. I am calling this method from ViewController to connect to the BLE device.

```
  -(void)connectToDevice:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral{
    
     [[AppDelegate app] cbCentral].delegate = self;
     [[[AppDelegate app] cbCentral] connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];

    }
```

This method is for discover the services for connected BLE device. I am calling method from NSOperation subclass

```
 -(void)calldiscoverServicesForPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral{
    
   [peripheral setDelegate:self];
   [peripheral discoverServices:@[[Utility SERVICE_UUID]]];
    
  }
```

This method is for write the data to BLE device. I am calling from NSOperation class for every second.

```
 -(void)writeDataToPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral Data:(NSData *)data{
    
        if (self.uartCharacteristic) {
            [peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:self.uartCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
        }
        
  }
```

CBCentralManager delegate methods for getting state of the device

```
 - (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    printf("Status of CoreBluetooth central manager changed %d \r\n",central.state);
    // Determine the state of the peripheral
    if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");
    }
    }

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral  *)peripheral {
    
    [delegate getConnectedPeripheral:peripheral];
    
   }
   
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {
    
    [delegate getConnectedPeripheral:peripheral];
}
     
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didFailToConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {
    
      NSLog(@"didFailToConnectPeripheral %@",peripheral);
    
 }
```

## pragma mark - CBPeripheralDelegate

```
 - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{

   // NSLog(@"Discovered servicea: %@", peripheral.services);

   for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {

     if ([service.UUID isEqual: [Utility SERVICE_UUID]]){
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:@[[Utility UART_UUID]] forService:service];
     }
   }
 }

  

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
   {

      for (CBCharacteristic *aChar in service.characteristics)
     {

        if ([aChar.UUID isEqual:[Utility UART_UUID]])
        {
        @synchronized(self.writeLock)
        {
            self.uartCharacteristic = aChar;
             //[peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:self.uartCharacteristic];

            [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:self.uartCharacteristic];

        }
    }    
  }
 }
  

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{

    NSString *tempStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: characteristic.value encoding: NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];

    [delegate getDataFromPeripheral:peripheral Data:characteristic.value];

}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
     if (error) {
         return;
    }
 }
```

And I am calling above class from NSOpeartion subclass

```
- (id)initWithConnectDevice:(ConnectDevice *)cDevice toPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral{
        
      if (self = [super init]) {


    executing = NO;
    finished = NO;
    [[[AppDelegate app] connectDevices] setDelegate:self];
    self.connectedPeripheral = peripheral;

    deviceParticulars = [[DeviceParticulars alloc] init];

    dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    dataString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
   }
   return self;

}

-(BOOL)isConcurrent{
     return YES;
}
- (BOOL)isExecuting {
     return executing;
}

- (BOOL)isFinished {
      return finished;
}

-(void) terminateOperation {
       
        [timer invalidate];

        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
        finished = YES;
        executing = NO;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
 
 }

- (void)start {

@autoreleasepool {

    if (self.isCancelled){
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        finished = YES;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        return;
    }

    writableString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [self createFile:[connectedPeripheral.identifier UUIDString]];

    [[[AppDelegate app] connectDevices] calldiscoverServicesForPeripheral:connectedPeripheral];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
}
}

-(void)timerFired:(id)sender{

if (self.isCancelled){

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    finished = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    return;
}

for (CBPeripheral *peripheral in [[AppDelegate app] peripheralsArray]) {

    [[[AppDelegate app] connectDevices] writeDataToPeripheral:peripheral Data:[self dataFromText:@"#RAL$"]];
    NSLog(@"Reading Peripheral::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::%@",[[AppDelegate app] peripheralsArray]);

  }
  }
```

I am allocating ConnectDevices class instance in Appdelegate. I am calling Nsoperation subclass from View Controller when BLE device is connected.

Problem, when i am writing data to one device it is working fine. But I connected to other device and write the data to second device i am getting bluetooth warning "is not valid characteristics for peripheral."

I think there is problem in my code.

Could you please help me

Please dont mind for this lot many lines of code.

many thanks

Comment: I am guessing it is because you are passing different peripherals but always using the same `self.uartCharacteristic` value but it is hard to tell because there is a lot of poorly formatted code here. It would be a lot cleaner if you just stored a reference to your singleton instead of calling `[[AppDelegate app] connectDevices]’ everywhere. It would probably be a good idea to wrap your CBPeripheral in another object so you could abstract a lot of the methods and the characteristic property

Comment: Thanks Paulw11. Please check the updated question. How can I create  self.uartcharacteristic for every device in ConnectDevice class. Please dont hesitate. I am new to this mutilthreading. I didn't understand the "CBPeripheral in another object". Could you please explain little more. Please help me.

Comment: What I meant was to create another object which has a CBperipheral as a property and can also store your characteristics etc associated with that peripheral.

Comment: Thanks alot.What I am understanding, create an object CBPeripheral in ConnectDevice class and assign the new CBPeripheral to this local object in Write Method. Is that Right?

Comment: I would create it as soon as you first learn about the peripheral - either in didDiscoverPeripheral or didRetrievePeripheral depending on how you are discovering the peripheral

Comment: Thanks for reply. As I already creat an object of CBCharacteristics and every time I am assigning new value to that. Is this right? Could you please help me. I am struggling with this issue for 2 days. please  help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59347/discussion-between-user3774439-and-paulw11).

Comment: Thanks alot paul I am able read the data from multiple devices
But I have one issue, After getting the data from multiple device, I am reloading tableview but tableview is flashing the labels. For example, two rows are in tableview contains two labels each. When I call reload tableview, displaying data in first row and second row will be empty and when displaying second row, first row will be empty. like that it is flashing please help me how can i solve this

Comment: I suggest you ask another question showing the relevant code (ie cellForRowAtIndexPath, the method where you reload the data)

Comment: Paul, please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366538/update-labels-in-uitableviewcell-from-multiple-threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate model class for peripheral and call from my view controller. That solve my issue. Thanks a lot Paul.