# Update labels in UITableViewCell from multiple threads

Tags: ios, uitableview

After getting the data from multiple device, I am reloading tableview but tableview is flashing the labels. For example, two rows are in tableview contains two labels each. When I call reload tableview, displaying data in first row and second row will be empty and when displaying second row, first row will be empty. Like that it is flashing please help me how can I solve this

like this I am reloading tableview

```
[devicesTableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)
                                   withObject:nil
                                waitUntilDone:NO];
```

This is CellForAtIndexPath Method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"DeviceCustomTableViewCellIdentifier";

    devicesCustomTableViewCell = (DeviceCustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (devicesCustomTableViewCell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DeviceCustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        devicesCustomTableViewCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    DeviceDetails *deviceDetailsEntity = [devicesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    devicesCustomTableViewCell.deviceName.text = deviceDetailsEntity.deviceLocalName;

    for (int i=0; i<[dataArray count]; i++) {
        DeviceParticulars *deviceParticulars = [dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([[[deviceParticulars.peripheral identifier] UUIDString] isEqualToString:deviceDetailsEntity.deviceAddress]) {

            devicesCustomTableViewCell.temperatureValueLabel.text = deviceParticulars.tempReadOutStr;



   }
```

In this, **DeviceDetails** class is core data class, In that I am saving BLE device name as per requirement.

**DeviceParticulars** class is NSObject class for saving data from multiple BLE devices like I am getting temperature from multiple devices. I am displaying Temp values in tableview.

**dataArray** is an array contains **DeviceParticulars** object.

Comment: What does the `reloadData` method do?  If you are using storyboards then prototype cells are preferred and they avoid the whole `if cell==nil...` issue

Comment: Also, you could probably replace the `dataArray` with an NSDictionary using the device identifier string as the key.  You wouldn't need to loop through the devices then

Comment: When I m getting data from BLE devices, I am calling tableview reload data for every second. Because I want to get the data from BLE device for every second. I am not using Storyboards.

Comment: Actually in **DeviceParticulars** class, there are number of variables like temperature, maxTemp. MinTemp etc..If I will take **NSDictionary** how can I get the values **DeviceParticulars** class

Comment: The key would be the device id and the value would be the DeviceParticulars instance.

Comment: Thanks alot Paul. I have basic question. Can I allocate 'NSmutableDictionary' in AppDelegate then I can Use through out the project. Is that correct way. Please suggest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59559/discussion-between-user3774439-and-paulw11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading the entire table every time a peripheral value changes is expensive and, as you are seeing, has visual impacts.

You can change your custom cell to act as a delegate to your model object - `DeviceParticulars`

In your DeviceParticulars.h file, register the delegate property and protocol

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) id delegate;

@protocol DeviceParticularsDelegate
- (void)didUpdateDevice:(DeviceParticulars *)device;
@end
```

In your DeviceParticulars.m file, where you update readings, call

```
[self.delegate didUpdateDevice:self];
```

Then in your DeviceCustomTableViewCell.h, add `<DeviceParticularsDelegate>` to the class definition and add a property to store your deviceParticulars

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) DeviceParticulars *myDevice;
```

In the .m implement the delegate method

```
-(void)didUpdateDevice:(DeviceParticulars *)device {
   // Update cell labels as required
}
```

and implement `prepareForReuse`

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    self.myDevice.delegate=nil;  // Remove this cell as delegate for existing device;
}
```

Finally, set the delegate in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"DeviceCustomTableViewCellIdentifier";

    devicesCustomTableViewCell = (DeviceCustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (devicesCustomTableViewCell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DeviceCustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        devicesCustomTableViewCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    DeviceDetails *deviceDetailsEntity = [devicesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    devicesCustomTableViewCell.deviceName.text = deviceDetailsEntity.deviceLocalName;

    for (int i=0; i<[dataArray count]; i++) {
        DeviceParticulars *deviceParticulars = [dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([[[deviceParticulars.peripheral identifier] UUIDString] isEqualToString:deviceDetailsEntity.deviceAddress]) {

            deviceParticulars.delegate=deviceCustomTableViewCell;   //Set the delegate
            devicesCustomTableViewCell.myDevice=deviceDetails;      //Set device property

            devicesCustomTableViewCell.temperatureValueLabel.text = deviceParticulars.tempReadOutStr;


   }
```

Comment: Thanks alot paul. I will try and let you know. Once thanks again thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually `DeviceParticulars` class is only for storing values in variables like Temp, MaxTemp, MinTemp. I am not updating reading in that class. I am getting data in `MyPeripheral` class as you said in earlier question and I am assigning values  to `DeviceParticulars` variables. please dont hesitate. thanks

Comment: That's ok. You can still retrieve the delegate property from the deviceparticulars object  and then invoke the delegate method from the MyPeripheral class

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried as you said. But same behaviour in tableview like one cell labels are empty when other cell labels are retriving the data

Comment: When you are retrieving the data do you clear the array that drives `numberOfRowsInSection`?  Are you still calling reload data ?

Comment: No i am not clearing the array. But I am reloading the tableview

Comment: You don't need to reload the table unless you discover a new peripheral - the delegate method lets the cell update its labels directly

Comment: `didUpdateDevice` method is not calling. In CellForRowindexpath, **` if ([[[deviceParticulars.peripheral identifier] UUIDString] isEqualToString:deviceDetailsEntity.deviceAddress]) {
deviceParticulars.delegate=devicesCustomTableViewCell;   //Set the delegate  devicesCustomTableViewCell.myDevice=deviceParticulars;      //Set device property
}`**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59572/discussion-between-paulw11-and-user3774439).

Comment: Thanks alot paul. I have tried with `NSMutableDictionary` instead of `dataArray`. Now the flickering was not happening even I am reloading the tableview for every second. Thanks alot for your idea.

Comment: Good. I guess that iterating through the array for each cell takes a reasonable amount of time.  Particularly as now that I look at the code again you continue to loop even after you have found the matching object

Comment: Paul I need one help. I want to know the basics of threading and also objective C. i want to improve my knowledge in Inheritance, Encapsulation and Interface etc.. Could you please suggest me or any book is availble for free. please let me know. Once again thanks alot.

Comment: It has been a **long** time since I studied this stuff at University, so I don't know what it out there.  I had a quick look at iTunes University and there are some courses on OO programming. Maybe take a look at those

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method for iOS 6 and later. It will automatically instantiate a cell if there is no reusable one, so you don't have to check if cell==nil. Not sure what causes your problems but I think it's worth to try it.
Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply.But I am already using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath in my code.

Comment: I can't see the `forIndexPath:` part. Please update your code.

Comment: I tried as you suggest but I am getting exception **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier DeviceCustomTableViewCellIdentifier - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'**